# Bundler error trying to install stripe gem on Rails 4.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am new to Rails and trying to install the stripe gem onto my Rails 4.2.4 project to process credit card payments.

In my Gemfile I've added `gem 'stripe', '~> 1.36'`

However, when I run `bundle install`, I get the error in my screenshot below pertaining to:

```
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
```

Please see enclosed screenshot of my Gemfile and also my terminal.

I would be grateful for assistance please.

[image]

[image]

Comment: why are you editing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some basic tools may be missing from your system.  It's not clear how much you've got working at this point before progressing to the new gem.  However assuming you are on a Mac I recommend looking at [these instructions](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan).  You may also need the command-line tools installed using `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: I've got all of this

Comment: John credit to you sir, When I opened up my Xcode the license required renewal. I done such and it worked, thank you very much.